# Using css to make google maps api circular

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I am using `border-radius: 50%;` to make the map circular.  The problem I am having is when the page loads the map is square for a second before the map becomes circular. Here is the jsfiddle I created https://jsfiddle.net/tnk240zb/2/.  When you click the play button the map is square for a second.  Is there a way to get the image to appear circular so it does not show up square for a second?

**code snippet:**

```css
#bubble {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 85px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
  border-top-right-radius: 40px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 8px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

img {
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

#map-canvas {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bubble">
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>

  <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <p id="user"></p>
    <p id="plan"></p>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
  (function(window, google, lat, lng) {
    var options = {
        center: {
          lat: lat,
          lng: lng
        },
        zoom: 5
      },
      element = document.getElementById('map-canvas')
    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, options)
  }(window, window.google, 37.791350, -122.436883));
</script>
```

Comment: Where in the page do you specify the style? If not in the head -- try there.

Comment: @plntxt.  The style is for #map-canvas in the css

Comment: Could you fix the fiddle so it loads the map?

Comment: @Aaron - I mean where in your (non-jsfiddle) document are you applying the style to the div?  Is it in a stylesheet?

Comment: @plntxt, I have a style tag in the header of the page

Comment: @yuriy636, I changed the jsfiddle link so it should now show the map

Comment: Also not sure if you noticed, but since it is googlemaps embedded, you can drag it, etc... and it falls back to the square shape on drag as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The div that renders the map per se (`#map-canvas div .gm-style div`) uses `z-index: 0` in its inline style:

```
<div tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; margin: 0px; cursor: url(&quot;https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur&quot;) 8 8, default;">
```

Set your `#map-canvas`'s `z-index` higher than 0, and it will work fine:

```
#map-canvas {
  /* (...) */
  z-index: 1;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/tnk240zb/3/

Answer (score 1):

Put the map in a `.wrapper` div.

Then, add a [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) to that div and give it a `radial-gradient` background with the **middle part being transparent**

The other background color has to match your document background. in this case it's white.

Then add `pointer-events:none` to the overlay so you **can click through it**.

this also prevents the problem from occuring when you move around and drag in the map.

It will always maintain the `border-radius`

**Side-note:** *your design idea breaks Google maps terms and conditions as you are hiding the google logo. If you must go through with this, be sure to read the terms and conditions really well*

**Working example:**

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 60%, white 40%);
}
```

```html
<!-- initilize map -->
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: 40.674,
        lng: -73.945
      },
      zoom: 12,
    })
  }
</script>



<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="map" style='width: 100%; height: 100%;'></div>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDHu4QBgWONqtdOWVLTW5XZ51B1eOU6SWw&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```